# Plot without reordering x values in plotnine

Tags: python

Please consider the following code:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict as od
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

d = {"A1.1": 4, "A1.2": 12, "A1.12": 13, "B10.1": 10}

def sorter(item):
    key, _ = item
    l, n = key.split(".")
    l = ord(l[0])*1000 + int(l[1:])*100
    return l+int(n)
d = od(sorted(d.items(), key=sorter))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['n_files'])
df.index.name = "fld"
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```

with output:

```
     fld  n_files
0   A1.1        4
1   A1.2       12
2  A1.12       13
3  B10.1       10
```

In the actual code, `d` is a dictionary with folder names as keys and number of files as values. As you can see, the `fld` column has the rows ordered according to the `sorter` function. This function serves to order the values using the integer number after the `.`: without that function values would be ordered lexicographically. For example, `A1.12` would come before `A1.2`. Instead, I want `A1.12` to be after `A1.2`.

If I plot the data using `plotnine.ggplot`, values are ordered lexicographically along the x axis.

```py
from collections import OrderedDict as od
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import *

d = {"A1.1": 4, "A1.2": 12, "A1.12": 13, "B10.1": 10}

def sorter(item):
    key, _ = item
    l, n = key.split(".")
    l = ord(l[0])*1000 + int(l[1:])*100
    return l+int(n)
d = od(sorted(d.items(), key=sorter))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['n_files'])
df.index.name = "fld"
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df.head())

(
    ggplot(df, aes(x='fld', y='n_files')) 
    + geom_bar(stat='identity') 
    + scale_x_discrete(name="subfolder")
    + scale_y_continuous(name="n. of files")
    + theme(
        figure_size=(12, 4), 
        axis_text_x=element_text(rotation=90, hjust=1, size=12),
        
    )
)
```

[image]

Question:
how do I tell plotnine to keep the order it finds in the dataframe?

Furthermore, as a secondary question, is there any way to change the title of the two axes without specifying also their type (e.g., `scale_x_discrete`)?
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plotnine has a [nice tutorial](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/miscellaneous-order-plot-series.html) regarding custom sorting.
For specific ordering a [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html#pandas.Categorical) variable can be used.

To define labels and titles, [`labs`](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.labels.labs.html) can be added to ggplot.

[image]

```py
# [...your code until ggplot ...]

df["fld_cat"] = pd.Categorical(df['fld'], categories=df['fld'])

print(
    ggplot(df, aes(x='fld_cat', y='n_files'))
    + geom_bar(stat='identity')
    + labs(y='Number of Files', x='Folder Category', title='Files and Folders')
    + theme(
        figure_size=(12, 4),
        axis_text_x=element_text(rotation=90, hjust=1, size=12),
    )
)
```